# Include exclude packages in serverless yml from same folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a node_modules folder from there i want to exclude only few modules but other modules should be added while packaging. How can i do that.Also how to exclude some modules using regex. like in my node_modules I have created custom modules that starts with md-request, md-models etc. so i want to exclude only these modules from packaging.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's most likely you're trying to exclude dev-dependencies. Install your dev dependencies using `npm i some-dependency --save-dev` and, by default, Serverless will not pack them into the final artifact.

If that's not sufficient, you can **exclude** everything and **include** only what you need.

You can see how Serverless behaves when packaging an artifact as well as seeing how to exclude/include dependencies on the [official docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/)

Here's an example (extracted from their docs) to **exclude** node_modules but to keep node_modules/node-fetch (which is pretty much what you're looking for):

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - '!node_modules/node-fetch/**'
```

And this is how you can **include** only what you need:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - src/**
  include:
    - src/function/handler.js
```

**EDIT**: after the OP's comment, here's how to handle the desired behaviour:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/my_module_1/**
    - node_modules/my_module_2/**
    - node_modules/my_module_3/**
    - node_modules/my_module_4/**
```

If the module names are very close to each other like the above, you can use the wildcard `*` to exclude them all in a one-liner:

```
package:
  exclude: 
    - node_modules/my_module_*/**
```

**EDIT 2**: Here's a working example (see that I am excluding aws-sdk):

```
package:
 exclude:
  - node_modules/aws-sdk/**
```

Since the package is too large and I am not able to see it through AWS Lambda's console, I am attaching two screenshots - one with exclude and one without exclude (see how the package size changes).

With exclude:

[image]

Without exclude:

[image]

This way you don't even need to add the '!node_modules/whatever-i-want-to-keep' argument

**EDIT 3**: Using the `*` wildcard in a sample project with manually created node_modules and respective my_module_* directories

[image]

[image]

Comment: as you first example I want just opposite of that, I have many modules that need to be include but exclude only 3 or 4. Its not dev-dependencies.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, your updated answer exclude that packages but what about to include other all packages, should i need to add ```include: -node_modules``` or what?

Comment: I have tried ```package:
  exclude:
    - ../../node_modules/wp-uap-logging
    - '!../../node_modules/**'``` like this, but it doesn't include any of the node_modules

Comment: It turns out you need to add /** to the module you want to exclude. So node_modules/wp-uap-logging becomes node_modules/wp-uap-logging/**

Comment: I have edited my answer with a working example. That way, you will be able to exclude only what you need, without needing to add anything back up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189388/discussion-between-thales-minussi-and-vaibhav-patil).

Answer (score 5):

I think serverless latest version (3.x) doesn't support the `exclude` keyword anymore. I was able to get this working using:

```
package:
  patterns:
    - src/**               # include only files from ./src/**/*
    - '!node_modules/**'   # exclude files from ./node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: The only thing helped me is to exclude all files from directory `'!./**'` and then include necessary only 'src/**'